# Function call as argument to print in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-call

```
a = 0
def f():
    global a
    a = 1
    print(a)
print(a, f(), a)
```

The output of the above code turns out to be the following:

```
1
0 None 1
```

Why is the function `f` called before printing the first argument `a`? Why is the value of the first argument `0`, even after the function call?

Answer (score 6):

What you get as output is:

```
1
0 None 1
```

When you call `print()` it computes the elements to be printed first. As you have `print(a)` inside your `f()` what you get first is `1`. Then, it starts printing. The value of `a` is `0` before you call the function. When you print a function that doesn't return anything, you get `None`. As you change the value globally, you get `1` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is printing, not returning, so there's no value when `f()` is called.

Basically, the order of things is this: Interpreter sees print, evaluates `a` (it's zero), then sees it needs to evaluate `f()` before it knows what to print, calls `f`, which gets you the `1` printed above, then evaluates `a` again (it's now 1). The line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not 0 after the function call, but before it.
The first a in your second print statement is passed in before f is called.
And why do you print f ()? It returns nothing (None)

Answer (score 1):

Python will run the `a = 0` line first, then define - but NOT run - the function `f()`, and then run the `print(a,f(),a)` call.  Therefore, the first print will be `a` after it has been defined with value 0, then the second print will call the function `f()`, which does not have a return and therefore will  print `None`.  Finally, you will print the value that `f()` assigned to `a`, which will be 1.